# How can I dynamically fill an Excel combobox with the content of a named table on a different sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

on one Excel sheet I have a combobox.

On another sheet, I have a table with a named column ("KontoNr") which should feed into the combobox. The table and column are named in the name manager and are shown as `=tabKontenplan` and `KontoNr =tabKontenplan[KontoNr]`.

Now I am unsuccessfully trying to fill the comboxbox like this:

```
combobox.listfillrange = "=tabKontenplan![KontoNr]"
```

And

```
combobox.listfillrange = "=KontoNr"
```

also does not work.
There ist no error, the combobox just remains empty... why is that?

Comment: So `KontoNr` is a named range???

Comment: Ah, the listbox is an ActiveX worksheet control.

Comment: Yes, "KontoNr" is the naming, added that to my post, thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added an empty ActiveX `ListBox` control on a worksheet, then typed a couple of random values in a `Range` on that worksheet, named that range `VALUES`, and then added this code in the worksheet's code-behind:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    ListBox1.ListFillRange = "VALUES"
End Sub
```

And that's all I needed to do. Remove the `=` in front of your named range, and it "just works". Make sure the defined name is in scope, and all will go well.

If the named range is *scoped* to the other worksheet, it won't work. Delete the name and re-create it in *workbook scope*.

Comment: Thank you, I had the name defined in worksheet scope. After setting a new name with the correct scope it works!

Comment: Hi, your solution works in my workbook if I define the range "VALUES" as you did for example like this
"=Tabelle2!$A$7:$A$10".
If want the values to be part of a range which is defined as a table the namemanager defines the source as 
"=tabKtos[Nummern]".
("tabKtos" being the name of the table, "Nummern" being the headline of the column in the sheet.).
Now, after I changed the source of "VALUES" in the namemanger, the script runs through, but in the combobox no entries appear. Any idea how to fix this???
Thx

Comment: Yes. The most important part is the *scope* of the defined name though.

Comment: I hit enter too soon, hadn't finished with my problem... plz see my edit above.

Comment: Can't repro, works perfectly fine here, with `VALUES` being defined as a workbook-scoped name referring to `=Table1[b]`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that "another sheet" is Sheet2,

```
no good: combobox.listfillrange = "=" & Sheet2.Range("KontoNr").Address
```

A corrected answer:

```
combobox.listfillrange = "=Sheet2!" & Sheet2.Range("KontoNr").Address
```

Comment: Unparameterized `.Address` will only contain the cell addresses of the range, without the qualifying worksheet name, e.g. `$A$1:$A$10` - making the list source even *more* ambiguous. Also when accessing named ranges, use the `Names` collection for a more explicit call into defined `Names`.

Comment: the correction should have been obvious, right? btw, what's "Unparameterized " And PLEASE, post an answer with the use of Names collection ;)

Comment: `.Address(External:=True)` is parameterized, and returns the fully-qualified address string, including the workbook filepath, sheet name, and range address. *That* would be usable. "Unparameterized" means "without parameters", but that should have been obvious, right? I don't need to post another answer that uses the `Names` collection, because all that's needed is the literal name - as long as the defined name is in-scope... like my answer already says.

Comment: Removed the downvote after seeing the edit. Still overkill though.

Comment: to Mat's Mug: you wrote "as long as the defined name is in-scope...". Correct, but we do not know that about the presented case.

Comment: Sure. Let's let the OP decide if they want to fix their code by removing 1 character, or by hard-coding worksheet names into string literals.